# Will Xcode 7.3.1 work on macOS 10.12?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, xcode8

I want to install and try out the new features of macOS 10.12. Also I really want to work on Xcode 8.0. But the same time I have some client projects which should written on Swift 2.2 [ Xcode 7.3.1 ], I don't want use Swift 2.3 or Swift 3.0.

So is it possible to install Xcode 7.3.1 in macOS 10.12? Is there any hacky way to do this?

---

**Yes I have successfully installed both `Xcode 7.3.1` and `Xcode 8.0` in my `macOS Sierra`.**

Now using both Xcodes. But whenever I run my project using `Xcode 7.3.1` I am getting this error `DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 6s'. Check the system log for errors.` I don't know the actual reason for this. I have googled for the answers but those suggestions didn't help me. But at the same time I can run projects in Xcode 8.0 in Simulator, no errors, nothing.

If anyone came to see this, Please let me know your comment.

Comment: @Bhadresh Already checked, didn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error, How fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this)

Comment: Does Sierra XCode works with iOS 8.0 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can absolutely install Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS Sierra alongside the beta version of Xcode 8.

If you are having issues running Xcode 7.3.x or running the simulator:

1. Reinstall Xcode 7.3.x from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.
2. Manually attach the debugger to your process as outlined in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37828996/2415822).

Comment: Downloading now then.

Comment: I've installed macOS and is having quite a number of issues with XCode 7.3.1 - currently both issues with starting Simulator and doing code signing. Both with more or less cryptic error messages.

Comment: Thanks @PeterTheill, I'll let you know if I hear anything from Apple.

Comment: I re-installed XCode 7.3.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and now I'm at least able to start my Simulator again.

Comment: Oh nice, Didn't think about. I just came back to El Capitan.

Comment: While you can install Xcode 7.3.1 on Sierra, it is not supported.

Comment: How do you install it from the downloads page?  Doesn't it just link to the App Store?

Comment: @milesper navigate to https://developer.apple.com/download/, log in with your developer account, and click the Xcode 8 Beta download link.

Comment: @milesper you can get it from the App Store or the "more" section of the developer downloads page: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Thanks @JAL that's what I needed

Comment: How did you install xcode 8(official) without replacing previous xcode 7.3.1(previous) on macOS Sierra.Any Help please?I want to use both Xcode because I am afraid of migration.I need to do step by step first.

Comment: @6245Htarwara I upgraded to Xcode 8 from the App Store and then downloaded Xcode 7.3.1 from Apple's developer portal.

Comment: @JAL ,So was application appear separately on Application Menu?or just it overwrite on Xcode 8?Did you use same Apple ID that you update the Xcode on App Store and Developer Portal?

Comment: @6245Htarwara I used all the same Apple IDs.  When you download Xcode 7, the application will also be called "Xcode."  I renamed it to "Xcode_7" before copying it to my Applications folder

Comment: Because I am experiencing Error ITMS 90167 since I upgrade my OS to macOS Sierra.They won't let me upload on Xcode 7.3.1.Thats the problem.And I still don't want to migrate because some of my library on cocoa pod didn't support Swift 2.3.So,I need to know for sure.Any help?

Answer (score 3):

To keep Xcode 7.3.1 running again besides Xcode 8.2 on macOS Sierra 10.12.2 I had to clean the following folders:

```
~/Library/Developer/
~/Library/Application Support/Developer
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
```

Even cleaning the userdata of the specific project was helpful:

```
projectname.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
projectname.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
```

After restarting the mac and trying to open the project it crashed again because there was already content in this folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins
```

After deleting these plug-ins again it finally worked!

Comment: That last directory doesn't exist on my machine.

Comment: I installed these plug-ins before with [alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/). If you haven't installed any there don't has to be such a folder. The detailed message of the error from the Xcode crash gave me the hint to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7.3.1 and Sierra is a non-supported configuration. While most of it will work, things like running a project on the simulator won't.

Comment: Okay. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be aware that you need the current public releases of macOS (El Capitan) and Xcode (7.3) to create and submit archives to the iTunes App Store. Archives created with beta versions Xcode (8b1), or with the current Xcode 7.3 on a beta version of  macOS (Sierra 10.12b1) won't be accepted (submission process fails). It's advised you backup your system before installing the macOS beta, and/or install the beta OS on a new partition. You can also install the current OS and Xcode on a small partition (10-20GB or so) if you'll need to make a submission in the next 3 months, and remove it when the public releases are available. It takes a little setup, tho, to configure your signing certs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed OS X Sierra and I was working with XCode 7.2. I found some alignment, issues when the XCode run in Sierra. I have reported to the bug reporting centre. I got  reply from the apple team that XCode 7.x versions are not supported in OS X Sierra and all the bugs has been closed. They recommends XCode 8 in OSX 10.12.