# Can I upload Xcode builds on macOS 10.12

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, macos-sierra

Will I be capable of submitting an app with Xcode 7.3.1  while on the macOS 10.12 beta? According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803916/will-xcode-7-3-1-work-on-macos-10-12), it is possible to run Xcode 7 alongside macOS 10.12.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you can! But if you're tying to do this, you will find two problems.

1. `no .app file provided in bundle`

Build with Xcode 7.3.1 then upload using Xcode 8 [Beta]. This will allow you to upload the archive.

2. When trying to submit to the store you will be faced with this error message:

   `New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and tvOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta OS X builds.`

This is because your archive contain the Sierra's mark! I just solved this problem yesterday.

When you archived your app, find your archive in the Organizer, and then:

- "Show in finder";
- "Show package contents";
- In the "xx.xcarchive" file, find the "Products"-"Applications"-"xx.app"(xx is your app's name), "Show package contents" again;
- Finally, you can see there has a file named"Info.plist", open it;
- Edit the value with a key named "BuildMachineOSBuild", I just change it to "15F34"(it's "El Capitan 10.11.5" 's version);

After that, you can upload this archive use  Xcode or Application Loader, whatever you want!

Comment: Thank you! I almost decide to remove Sierra and install El Capitan just to upload my app. And I supprised that Apple let user edits archive before uploading like that.

Comment: I don't see a "Show package contents" option

Comment: thank you.. your way is the best way to solve this is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Decided to try it out myself. Both methods of exporting through Xcode and Application Launcher failed with an error stating there was `no .app file provided in bundle`. Best to stay away from the macOS 10.12 beta if you want to continue developing for iOS 9.