# How do I find my IOS app's archive file?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipa, macos-sierra

I have Mac OS Sierra. Unfortunately, I cannot upload my app due to a bug in Xcode 7.3.1 that makes it impossible to upload to iTunes Connect from Mac OS Sierra.

I have found a work around: [Can I upload Xcode builds on macOS 10.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823382/can-i-upload-xcode-builds-on-macos-10-12)

However, it says I need to find my app's "archive" file. I believe that is the same thing as my app's .ipa file.

Where would my app's .ipa file be located?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using Window->Organizer, you can select your archive in the list and choose the `export` option.  Then export as `save for iOS App Store Deployment`.  Once the process is done it will allow you to save the exported file as a folder that contains your ready IPA file.

[image]

Comment: This is also how you get the `ExportOptions.plist` file if needed.

Answer (score 81):

They are stored here:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
```

In that folder you will find a bunch of folders by date.

Alternatively, open XCode, go to `Window` -> `Organizer`. Right-click the archive you are looking for and select "Show in Finder"

Answer (score 7):

> However, it says I need to find my app's "archive" file. I believe that is the same thing as my app's .ipa file.

You need to unbelieve that. You can *make* an *.ipa* file from your app's archive, but you don't usually need to do that any more.

Okay, so, step one: choose Product -> Archive. That builds the archive.

Step two: There might be no step two, because the first step might take you to the built archive. But if not, choose Window -> Organizer -> Archives. There's your archive, and the upload process can be performed directly from this window.

Comment: matt, but what needs to happen if Archive is greyed out ?

Comment: @Greg That's a completely different question. If you don't know how to make an archive, you need to find out.