# Can't validate or upload app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm working on the last OS : Sierra 10.12.5, and XCode 8.3, and I can't upload my app, I get this error:

> This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)

And I cannot validate my app to, here is the error:

> New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions
>   of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with
>   beta software including beta macOS builds.

I did some searches, I tryed it:
[Can I upload Xcode builds on macOS 10.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823382/can-i-upload-xcode-builds-on-macos-10-12)

With the number code of Sierra, but still doesn't work.

With Application Loader:
[image]

Comment: Whats your xcode version?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of apple servers, you can check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421).
Have you try to upload your .ipa file by Application Loader ?

Comment: In Mac App store the latest public version of Xcode is 8.3.3 and as error message said your Xcode version is deprecated you need to update your Xcode version to be able to upload your app .ipa file to iTunes connect.

Comment: Check this [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12). And try to install it. It should resolve your issue

Comment: Sometimes Mac App store shows updates late and as I understand this is the case because your Xcode version is 8.3(which is deprecated for uploading apps) but latest version of Xcode 8.3.3 which was released on June 5, try to install latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error while uploading the app. 
Use application loader for uploading.

1. Create an ipa.
2. Save it
3. Open application loader.
4. Select ipa
5. Upload the ipa.